# Page Event and Clearing the Fields on a ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I know that asp.net is all about events , but I don't quite get how the events work.

I have the requirement to build a web form that will submit and send an e-mail to a an specified email address with the `TextBox` and `CheckBox` values and some HTML on the email body. The issue I am having is that I need to:

1. Make sure that the information is gone when the user goes back in the browser or refresh the page.
2. I need to also let the user print a page with all form filled out, before reaching the second page, (confirmation) and after the validation was successful. Currently I have an event `OnClientClick` on the submit button and that calls window.print function, but what I really want is to print after the page is submited. and before the confirmation open. On top of my head I only can think on having all information passed to a intermediate second page , and then on the Page Loading Event on the third page print ..

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the textboxes are empty you would need to ensure the page wasn't cached; see this MSDN on [Setting the Cacheability of a Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or just adding

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

to prevent browsers from serving up cached versions of your pages - so clicking back on the browser should no longer retain the values entered.

You could consider turning off viewstate for the page, this is the .NET mechanism that persists the textbox values automagically for you (you could turn it off just for the textboxes you wish to prevent from being re-populated).

Typically in .NET I would have the button click event fire methods, use this event to do the things you need, send the email, print the form and clear any values entered (just to be safe)

```
protected void SendMailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMail();
    PrintForm();
    ClearForm();
}
```

Then

```
protected void PrintForm()
{
    // send form values to a page that handles the printing
}
```